# Dot product of a sinusoid with a complex tone in Octave

Tags: math, octave

I am trying to figure out how to solve this problem;

> Now make a new sinusoid with amplitude 1 and frequency 1000Hz.
>   Calculate the dot product of this sinusoid with your complex tone
>   using vector  multiplication between the heterodyne and the transposed
>   complex tone signal.

So far no good. I have managed to represent a complex tone by:

```
octave:65> t = [0 : 441];
octave:68> A = 0.25;
octave:69> x = A*sin(2*pi*t*441) + A*sin(2*pi*t*882) + A*sin(2*pi*t*1323) + A*sin(1764*pi*t*2);
```

And the new sinusoid

```
 octave:66> y = sin(pi*2*t*1000);
```

Now I find myself trapped with the heterodyne concept and its application. I can tell that the vector multiplication would be like;

```
octave:75> abs(y*x')
```

However, parameter 'y' which needs to be the the heterodyne of 'y'(I guess), is driving me nuts...

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by "heterodyne" here. If it's anything like the [description on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterodyne#Mathematical_principle), I'm not sure how it applies to this situation. Do you have an instructor you can ask for clarification?

Comment: Are you talking about heterodyne as in the super heterodyne receiver? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superheterodyne_receiver

Comment: Problem is I am studying from home, thus I have no instructor. Seems quite ambigous for me. I honestly do not have a clue about what is exactly asked regarding heterodyne. What you see is as much as you get. It says I need to dig into the heterodyne term, but I do not how could it be applyed here.

Comment: I asked in MathExchange too. A user gave a nice aproximation to application of heterodyne term to the exercise, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281720/dot-product-of-a-sinusoid-with-a-complex-tone-in-octave/1282122#1282122